# A generic regex that will work for the following kind of string

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have a function that accepts a string.

```
ignoreWords.contains(InString.toLowerCase());
```

I want this `Instring` in a format as `"abc"` that is any string without any character. But my `InString` may come in a format as `"abc"`, or `",abc"`. For now, I am handling it as below

```
ignoreWords.contains(text.toLowerCase().replaceAll(",","")));
```

But this `Insting` may be in a format as `".abc"` or `"abc."` or `"(abc)"`. I don't want to write multiple `replaceAll` function or to write multiple `if` statements to check whether the `InString` contains `,` or `.` etc.

The `InString` may be one of the following format `",abc"`, `"abc,"`, `".abc"`, `"abc."`, `",abc,"`, `".abc."`, `",abc."`, `".abc,"`, `"(abc)"`. There is a very less possibily that InString may come in this format also as `",(abc)"` or `"(abc),"` or `"(abc)."` or `".(abc)"` or `",(abc),"` or `".(abc)."`.

What can be the efficient way to write a single `replaceAll` call using a regex which gives a solution in a short and simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression as first parameter, so you could do this:

```
ignoreWords.contains(text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[.(),]", ""));
```

This will replace all `.`, `(`, `)` and `,` with an empty String.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even replace the other characters?

Check it the other way around:

```
boolean shouldIgnore(String inString, List<String> ignoreWords){
  for(String ignoreWord:ignoreWords){
    if(inString.contains(ignoreWord)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This way you check if the inString contains any of the to-be-ignored words without replacing anythin in the input string.

Comment: I want to return the instring.So if I made the return type as String and inside the if statement instead of return true if I write as  if(inString.contains(ignoreWord)){
      inString.toLowerCase().replaceAll(ignoreWord,"");
    } and once the loop is completed I will return the instring to the calling function. then It should work.